# jQuery tooltip hide disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I am looking to some jQuery plugin, which shows bubble with easy search form (one input and submit button). I found tooltip on jQuery ui, but I don't know how to disable auto hiding of that. (if i want to click inside the tooltip, it disappears).

This is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".search").click(function(){
         $( ".search" ).tooltip({content: $('#search_content').html()});
         $( ".search" ).tooltip("open");
        });});
```

So is there any better plugin for me or its the best and there is a way to solve it?

Thank's for your answers! :)

Comment: Wouldn't [`jQueryUI Dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) do the job?

Comment: A tooltip is a non-interactive view. It's not appropriate for placing something like a form inside of. Like the above comment suggested, look into using a Dialog.